# OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument writing tar file

Tags: python, python-requests, operating-system

I'm trying to download a 2.5 GB tar file and write that file to disk with Python. The following runs just fine with a different .tar file, but crashes with the tar file specified below:

```
import requests

url = 'http://pixplot.yale.edu/datasets/bain/photos.tar'
with open('photos.tar', 'wb') as out:
  r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
  out.write(r.content)
```

This raises:

```
<class 'requests.models.Response'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t.py", line 7, in <module>
    out.write(r.content)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Does anyone know what might cause this error? Any suggestions would be helpful!

NB: This problem only occurs in Python 3.x. If I switch to a 2.7 conda environment the snippet above runs fine.

Comment: I suspect you're using a 32-bit OS, so files are limited to 2GB.

Comment: Those were the days! This is 64 bits and I can wget the same file just fine, just can't write bytes with the snippet above...

Comment: @duhaime So how many bytes actually does get written to the file before you get an error?

Comment: @AndrewHenle If the system call is reporting an argument error, I wouldn't expect it to write anything.

Comment: Indeed the out file has size 0

Comment: @Barmar I'm assuming the Python `out.write()` call can be implemented with multiple underlying calls to the OS `write()` library function and subsequent system call.  `EINVAL` is a strange one to get for `write()`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Actually, my assumption is exactly the opposite: it's doing one write(), and it's getting an error because the size is >2GB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like there's a problem writing such a large amount to the file, try splitting it up into smaller chunks:

```
blocksize = 1000000000
for i in range(0, len(r.content), blocksize):
    out.write(r.content[i:i+blocksize])
```

I'm guessing Python 2.7 did this internally, but 3.5 doesn't.

Comment: You're right--writing in blocks works just fine! Do you have a sense why the code above would run fine in Python 2.7 but not in 3.5?

Comment: Maybe 3.5 was compiled in 32-bit mode instead of 64-bit.

Comment: aha! So it's not the OS bit mode but the python bit mode!

Comment: The problem with writing >2GB is strongly indicative of something having to do with 32-bit-ness.

Comment: @Barmar [Linux has a hard limit on how big a `write()` operation can be](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html):  "On Linux, write() (and similar system calls) will transfer at most
       0x7ffff000 (2,147,479,552) bytes ..."  Note that violating that is not specified to set `errno` to `EINVAL`.

Comment: Ah, maybe Python 2.x did the chunking, and Python 3.5 doesn't.